# Correlacionar vetores através do índice e atribuir valores diferentes

Tags: python-2.7, array-associativo

Possuo os seguintes vetores:

```
posicao_1 = [4, 62, 24, 18, 47, 62, 63, 78, 68, 87, 24, 18, 6, 8, 12, 17]

posicao_2 = [43, 61, 21, 19, 46, 63, 68, 72, 66, 89, 29, 10, 8, 7, 6, 15]
```

Preciso procurar no vetor POSICAO_1 o valor [24, 18].

```
posicao_1 = [4, 62, **24, 18**, 47, 62, 63, 78, 68, 87, **24, 18**, 6, 8, 12, 17]
```

Podemos observar que os mesmos se encontram nos índices [2, 3] e [10, 11] do vetor POSIÇÃO_1.

Após localizar esses valores, preciso percorrer o vetor POSIÇÃO_2 e atribuir valores aleatórios e DIFERENTES nos ÍNDICES [2, 3] e [10, 11] que localizei no vetor POSIÇÃO_1. Por exemplo:

Teria que atribuir valores aleatórios e DIFERENTES:

```
posicao_2 = [43, 61, **22, 30**, 46, 63, 68, 72, 66, 89, **31, 41**, 8, 7, 6, 15]
```

Possuo o script abaixo, que adiciona valores IGUAIS:

```
    ================================
    posicao_1 = [4, 62, 24, 18, 47, 62, 63, 78, 68, 87, 24, 18, 6, 8, 12, 17]
    posicao_2 = [43, 61, 21, 19, 46, 63, 68, 72, 66, 89, 29, 10, 8, 7, 6, 15]

    aleatorio = randrange(0, 100)

    pesq = [[24,18], [62,63]]

    for p in pesq:
        indices = [x for x in range(len(posicao_1)) if posicao_1[x:x+len(p)] == p ]

        for i in indices:
            posicao_2[i: i+len(p)] = [aleatorio] * len(p)

    print(posicao_2)        
    ==============================
```

Como modifico para que adicione VALORES DIFERENTES?

Alguém, por gentileza, poderia me ajudar?

Desculpa, caso não tenha sido muito claro, tentei explicar o máximo possível!

Comment: `posicao_2[i: i+len(p)] = random.sample(range(100), len(p) )` ou `posicao_2[i: i+len(p)] = [random.randrange(0,100)] * len(p)` se for para serem diferentes dois a dois

Comment: O Algoritmo funcionou corretamente, porém o que eu preciso é o seguinte

Nos índices [2, 3] e [10, 11] do vetor posicao_2 ele atribua tuplas com valores diferentes, por exemplo: [31,10]. Nos índices [2, 3] e [10,11].

Por exemplo, ele deve ficar assim:

posicao_2 = [43, 61, **31, 10**, 46, 63, 68, 72, 66, 89, **31, 10**, 8, 7, 6, 15]

Comment: Ou seja, a tupla deve possuir valores diferentes, porém a tupla deve ser igual.

Comment: Desculpa se não estiver sendo muito claro.

Comment: Conseguiu entender a ideia @Isac?

Comment: Por exemplo:
Usando essa lógica que você criou:

for i in indices:
            posicao_2[i: i+len(p)] = [aleatorio] * len(p)

São atribuídos nas posições [2,3] e [10, 11] os valores [16,16] e [16, 16]

Eu desejo que nas posições [2,3] e [10,11] sejam atribuídos os mesmos valores, porém a tupla deve ser diferente. Por exemplo, ao invés de [16, 16] e [16,16] seja [31,10] e [31, 10].

Comment: Aconselho-o  a aprofundar o estudo sobre programação para não ficar preso em trocas que são consideravelmente simples. Isso irá ajudar-lhe também a conseguir desenvolver novas lógicas para os seus objetivos com facilidade e não depender de ninguém. Será válido tanto para python como para outra linguagem qualquer uma vez que o importante é a lógica.

Comment: Obrigado @Isac. Você está correto. Já estou fazendo isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se precisa que cada "tuplo" encontrado seja substituído por um valor aleatório igual nas duas posições mas diferentes do sucessivos tuplos, basta gerar um novo aleatório antes de cada troca:

```
for i in indices:
    aleatorio = random.randrange(0,100)
    posicao_2[i: i+len(p)] = [aleatorio] * len(p)
```